# Uploading static executable to GIT project makes the file corrupted

Tags: git, github

I have a git project that has a number of python, js, etc files in it. One of the files is a compiled C program ('program.static') that runs fine in my project.

However, when I commit that file to git (its rather small, like 12 MB) and then try to pull it down to a new machine (or even the same machine after wiping that local copy of the git project) the file no longer works as an executable.

On OSX, if I try to run the static file, (e.g. `./program.static`) it will just immediately kill the process. If I copy/paste a local copy of `program.static` to the directory, it works fine.

How do you protect static files like this during the git commit/pull process?

Comment: Probably git is treating the file as text, and doing line ending conversions for some reason. Is there anything suspicious in your `.gitattributes`?

Comment: `git diff --numstat 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD -- | grep "^-" | cut -f 3` shows all the files that Git treats as binary (so it won't mutilate them). Does it contain `program.static`?

Comment: @Thomas You totally nailed it...the .gitattributes wasn't set correctly for the .static format (changed to binary and it works great now). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the .attributes to include the .static file format correctly preserves functionality of the file